# I'm installing graphics card drivers, and it's telling me to install these things, but i have NO idea what exactly it is actually telling me to do!

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati

I was trying to install my drivers for my graphics card, which is an AMD Radeon HD 6570, and when running the .run file, it first told me to download some packages first. Then i got another message telling me to install some other things, only this one doesn't make sense to me, as i am a n00b to Ubuntu. I have understood simple terminal commands like

```
sudo apt-get install <package>
```

but this is where being new kicks in, and i have no idea what to do...

Here's what it says. Can anyone tell me what to do, and help me make sense of what this says?

[(Click this for a picture of the text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3VZP.png)

ALSO, this MAY help. Here is the driver im installing: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86_64

Comment: I think those drivers are available from ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/a/47511/167115

Answer (score 2):

fglrx is actually available from apt-get.

First of all, you need to enable the restricted repository if it is not already enabled. [Click here for more info.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

To install fglrx, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

---

For future reference:

To search for stuff available through apt-get, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache search fglrx
```

to narrow the results, use grep like this:

```
apt-cache search fglrx | grep fglrx
```

---

Additionally, you can search for available proprietary drivers through the software center. [Click here for more info.](https://askubuntu.com/a/47511/167115)

---

Finally, if you insist on installing the downloaded drivers, you will need to run the following commands to install the needed packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

Comment: They don't seem to have the latest 15.11 Crimson drivers in the repo yet. If he wants those, he has to use the manual method. The last part of your answer should fix his dependency issues.

Comment: just a note, when you install using the manual method, you will have to manually reinstall  each time there is a kernel update.